# Large scale consecutive matrix multiplication applications

Tags: image-processing, parallel-processing, signal-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am running some experiments with matrix multiplication and I am looking for applications (preferably signal processing applications) where multiple input matrices A(i), [i=0,1.....] are multiplied with a kernel matrix B to produce multiple C(i) in the form C(i) = A(i)*B. The larger the i the better. This is the case for example in the training and recognition stage of face recognition via PCA. Are there other example applications where such computations are encountered even beyond signal processing?

Comment: Tensor contractions in quantum chemistry can be written to use this pattern. I can point you to code and help you generate results if you're interested.

Comment: Yes @Jeff please i would be definitely be grateful.

Comment: Please look up my email from my profile and we can discuss that way. Thanks.